# ¿Cómo concatenar Strings?

Tags: java

Quiero que el método `toString` devuelva esto: `nombrePersona(email)`

He hecho un método `toString`, pero me sale error. ¿Qué he hecho mal?

```
//metodo que muestra el valor de sus atributos
public String toString() {
    String mensaje= this.nombrePersona+ "("this.email")";
    return mensaje;
}
```

Comment: Hola bpico. Aunque esta pregunta era obvia, siempre incluye el mensaje de error que recibes. No es muy útil simplemente decir que recibes un error.

Comment: @sstan es un  error de compilación.

Comment: Es un error de compilación, perdona por no ponerlo @sstan

Answer (score 12, accepted):

En esta linea tienes que añadir `"+"`  para concatenar `Strings`:

```
String mensaje= this.nombrePersona+ "(" + this.email + ")";

                                        ↑            ↑
```

Answer (score 4):

No sé qué es lo que quieres sacar exactamente. Para que muestre el nombre junto con su email, una opción sería ésta:

```java
String nombrePersona="pepe";
String email="pepe@gmail.com";
String mensaje= nombrePersona+ "(" + email + ")";
System.out.println(mensaje);
```

Aunque el problema es que tienes que tener inicializado tanto `nombPersona` como `email`.

Comment: @Mariano la verdad es que lo probé en netbeans y no me fijé en la respuesta anterior, sorry :(.

Comment: @AnnaPS piensa que la funcion `toString()` no es solo esa que transforma un `int` en un `String`. Es usada con objetos propios para que muestren la información que queramos. Un `toString()`de la clase persona podría sacar la información completa de ella. En este caso busca que su `this`(supongo que objeto Persona) imprima "Nombre(email)" al igual que pudo poner "Nombre(Tlf)" ... etc

Comment: @AnnaPS Desde ya, está genial que aportes al sitio, y realmente es algo que me encantaría seguir viendo. Te pregunté como para **1.** ver si se podía agregar algo en tu respuesta (si se diferenciaba) **2.** comentar que se buscan respuestas de calidad, evitando repetir algo ya publicado... De todas formas, seguí buscando las preguntas nuevas en las etiquetas que más te interesen, que algo vas a encontrar (paciencia es la clave)... Cualquier duda sobre el uso del sitio esta [meta]

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias a tod@s! ya la tengo resuelta